# ASP.NET Read Event in Page_Init

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

That's pretty much it.  I need to read a server controls event, which will "occur" after Init, but I need to do it during Init.  The information is in there somewhere, how do I get to it?

EDIT:

Specifically, I am trying to find which MenuItem in a Menu was clicked.  It needs to be done in Page_Init because it drives some other code (which has to live in Page_Init).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily identify which control caused the event with something like:

```
public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
{
Control control = null;

string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
{
    control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
}
else
{
    foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
    {
        Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
        if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
        {
            control = c;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return control;
}
```

lifted from http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx

I've used this with success before although I've never actually needed event data - just knowledge of the event fired.

Comment: It will be in the request somewhere - when you say read a server control event, can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve and what type of controls /events you are dealing with. Thanks.

Comment: And the answer is: Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT")